Autodesk Platform Services 2LO in a PKCE App
My team is using a PKCE authentication flow for a webapp but to get the Autodesk Docs project members and companies there is need for a 2LO with grant_type client_credentials. Is it possible to make use of the Client Id and the code_challenge used in the PKCE to obtain a 2LO?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The API to get project users at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-projectsprojectId-users-GET/ supports both 2LO and 3LO access tokens
